# In one sentence, how would you summarize the teachings of Islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, terminology

Reading the Gospel of Jesus, I had the impression that the essence of Christianity can be found in Jesus' instructions to "love thy neighbour".

Does Islam have a similarly fundamental principle? If so, how would you express it?

Comment: The first kalima  or kalima-tayyab : **لآ اِلَهَ اِلّا اللّهُ مُحَمَّدٌ رَسُوُل اللّهِ**  means *" There is no God but Allah, Muhammad is the Messenger of Allah "*  would summerize the  teaching of Islam in one sentence. Though this whole sentence isn't mentioned  anywhere in the Quran.

Comment: Welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This is a subjective question and therefore a bad fit for any site on the stackexchange network. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help].

Answer (score 0):

There is of course more than one phrase of the Word of God that is important, and any answer to this question must be more or less a personal view.

In my view, the principal message in the Quran is

(18:107)

> **Those who believe and do righteous deeds, they will have the Gardens of Paradise for hospitality.**

This message is repeated many, many times in the Quran with slightly different wording (2:62, 2:82, 4:124, 10:26, 11:23, 16:30-32, 19:60, 23,8-11, 29:58, 39:73, 40:40, 46:13-14)

You cited Mark 12:28-31:

> One of the teachers of the law came and heard them debating. Noticing that Jesus had given them a good answer, he asked him, “Of all the commandments, which is the most important?”
> “The most important one,” answered Jesus, “is this: ‘Hear, O Israel: The Lord our God, the Lord is One. Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind and with all your strength.’ The second is this: ‘Love your neighbour as yourself.’ There is no commandment greater than these.”

These Words are cited from the Torah:

Deuteronomy 6:4-5

> Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is One. Love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength.

Leviticus 19:18

> Do not seek revenge or bear a grudge against any of your people, but love your neighbour as yourself. I am the LORD.

This is the Word of God, the One, the Eternal, the Provider and the Judge. The essence of Islam is to hearken to the Word of God as it has been revealed to Muhammad (p.b.u.h.) and the prophets who preceeded him.

The promise of the Quran that those who follow these principal rules will enter Paradise (Gospel terms: the Kingdom of God) has already been revealed through Jesus (p.b.u.h). There is no difference in the Word of God, and there is not much difference between those who follow the Word of God with all their heart.

The main difference to Jews and Christians of any denomination is that we trust in Muhammad and recognise him as a prophet.